# How do you do end-of-week rounding on a date field in C# (without using LINQ)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a weird date rounding problem that hopefully someone can solve.  My client uses a work week that runs from Monday through Sunday.  Sunday's date is considered the end of the week, and is used to identify all records entered in a particular week (so anything entered last week would have a WEEKDATE value of '10/26/2008', which is Sunday's date).

One little twist is that users enter records for the previous week up until 11 AM on the Monday of the current week.

So I need a function that starts with DateTime.Now and returns the week-ending date (no time part) according to the rules above.  Thanks for your help.  I have a solution that works, but I'm too embarassed to post it.

Oh, and I can't use LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public DateTime WeekNum(DateTime now)
{
    DateTime NewNow = now.AddHours(-11).AddDays(6);

    return (NewNow.AddDays(- (int) NewNow.DayOfWeek).Date);
}

public void Code(params string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(WeekNum(DateTime.Now));   
    Console.WriteLine(WeekNum(new DateTime(2008,10,27, 10, 00, 00)));
    Console.WriteLine(WeekNum(new DateTime(2008,10,27, 12, 00, 00)));
    Console.WriteLine(WeekNum(new DateTime(2008,10,28)));
    Console.WriteLine(WeekNum(new DateTime(2008,10,25)));


}
```

You may hard-code DateTime.Now instead of passing a DateTime object.  It just made testing easier this way.

Comment: DayOfWeek is Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 etc.?

Comment: @Joel: Sorry, posted too quickly.  Revised version should work.

Comment: Thanks, James. I added .Date to the return line, so I only get the date part.

Answer (score 4):

This passes for me as well:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
   DateTime sunday = DateTime.Parse("10/26/2008");
   DateTime nextSunday = DateTime.Parse("11/2/2008");

   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/21/2008")));
   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/22/2008")));
   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/23/2008")));
   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/24/2008")));
   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/25/2008")));
   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/26/2008")));
   Assert.AreEqual(sunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/27/2008 10:59 AM")));
   Assert.AreEqual(nextSunday, GetSunday(DateTime.Parse("10/27/2008 11:00 AM")));
}

private DateTime GetSunday(DateTime date)
{
   if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && date.Hour < 11)
      return date.Date.AddDays(-1);

   while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
      date = date.AddDays(1);

   return date.Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime GetMidnightFollowingSunday()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    return now.AddDays(7 - (int)now.DayOfWeek).Date;
}
```

If you need to start the new week after 11AM on Monday morning just subtract 11 hours from now but then it probably makes sense to name the method something else.

```
DateTime GetRecordDate()
{
    DateTime nowMinusOffset = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-11);
    return nowMinusOffset.AddDays(7-(int)nowMinusOffset.DayOfWeek).Date;
}
```

Comment: Close, but you were turning the current Sunday into the following Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

I've used these extensions with great success:

http://www.codeplex.com/DateTimeExtensions